# If Statement In PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm using the following script to load marker data into my map.

```
<?php 
require("phpfile.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node 

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); 
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); 
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server 

$connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$query = "select l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.address, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, count(f.locationid) as totalfinds from detectinglocations as l left join finds as f on l.locationid=f.locationid group by l.locationid"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each 

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE 
$node = $dom->createElement("marker"); 
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node); 
$newnode->setAttribute("locationid",$row['locationid']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("locationname",$row['locationname']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("address",$row['address']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("osgb36lat",$row['osgb36lat']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("osgb36lon",$row['osgb36lon']); 
$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds",$row['totalfinds']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML(); 

?>
```

I'd now like to extend the functionality of it further, by adding a new field that converts a numeric value to text. To be more precise if the 'totalfinds' figure is zero then I would like a field that says 'No items found' and if the value is greater than zero then this would return the text 'Items Found'.

From what I've read, I think that I'll need to do this via an 'If' Statement. I am a little new to this, but could someone perhaps confirm for me please whether this is the best way to go about it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `if`, ie

```
if($row['totalfinds'] == 0) $newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", "No items found");
else $newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds","Items Found");
```

instead of

```
$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds",$row['totalfinds']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in PHP. It is a concise way of doing the same thing an If-Else statement would:

`$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", ($row['totalfinds'] > 0 ? 'Items Found' : 'No items found'));`

is the same as

```
if ($row['totalfinds'] > 0) {
    $newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", 'Items Found');
} else {
    $newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", 'No items found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do an `if`, but short question mark notation would fit better in this scenario:

```
$found_string = ($totalfinds != 0 ? 'Items Found' : 'No items found');
```

of even shorter (when variable is not zero it equals to `true`):

```
$found_string = ($totalfinds ? 'Items Found' : 'No items found');
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this could be done more concisely with the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). But considering that you asked if this could be done with an `if` statement, and you are relatively new to php, here is how this might be accomplished using an `if` statement.

Change this line:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds",$row['totalfinds']);
```

to

```
if ($row['totalfinds'] > 0) {
     $foundText = 'Items Found';
} else {
     $foundText = 'No Items Found';
}
$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", foundText);
```

In case you're still curious, the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) solution looks like this:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("totalfinds", $row['totalfinds'] > 0 ? 'Items Found' : 'No Items Found');
```

This could also be accomplished by changing the MySQL query to use a [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

```
$query = "select l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.address, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, case when count(f.locationid) > 0 then 'Items Found' else 'No Items Found' end as totalfinds from detectinglocations as l left join finds as f on l.locationid=f.locationid group by l.locationid";
```